# Need to remap [ Win + . to Alt + . ] using AutoHotkey

Tags: windows, autohotkey, hotkeys, remap

I simply need help remapping Win + . to Alt + . using AutoHotkey! If you were wondering, this is the emoji panel shortcut. It's easier. quicker for me to use Alt as the modifier instead of Windows :)

my .ahk file reads:

> !.::
> Send, #.
> Return

but it just returns "::" text as a result.

I'm not a programmer (I'm an IT project manager) and I'm just trying to get this remap to work but am clearly missing something.

Help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works here:

**AHK v1**

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v1.1

!.:: Send #. ; one-line hotkey
```

**AHK v2**

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

!.:: Send "#."
```

Try it first in a script with no other code and close all other scripts, in case something else interferes.

Comment: THANK YOU! this worked! It also appears that I had to select which version of autohotkey I wanted to run (I think I was trying to use v2 code on v1 of the application. Thank you again!!!!!